# In lisp, how do I use the second value that the floor function returns?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

When I do (floor 4 3) I got

```
1
1/3
```

But how do I use that 1/3?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can for instance bind it to a variable using `multiple-value-bind`.

```
(multiple-value-bind (quot rem)
    (floor 4 3)
  (format t "The remainder is ~f~%" rem))
```

Another possibility, if you're *only* interested in one non-primary value, is `nth-value`.

```
(format t "The remainder is also ~f~%" (nth-value 1 (floor 4 3)))
```

For reference, see the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ag.htm).

Comment: If you are _only_ interested in the remainder, you can use `rem` or `mod` (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mod_r.htm).

Comment: @Svante Good point, thanks.  I was assuming the question was more about the general behaviour of multiple values, but that is not obvious from the original question.  hyh: If your problem was indeed the concrete one of finding the remainder from some calculation, use Svante's suggestions, it will make your code better by clearly stating your intention.

Comment: thanks for the hyperspec link I had no idea lisp just discards the second value.