# How to access multiple values returned by a function (e.g., cl:parse-integer)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, multiple-value

I'm trying to get three numbers out of a string

```
(parse-integer "12 3 6" :start 0 :junk-allowed t)
12 ;
2
```

Now this returns `2` as well, which is the number where it could be parsed.
So I can now give

```
(parse-integer "12 3 6" :start 2 :junk-allowed t)
3 ;
4
```

But how do I store the value of `2` and `4` that it returned. If I `setq` it into a variable only the `12` and `3` are stored?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please read the "theory" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781).

Briefly, you can bind the [multiple values](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_m.htm#multiple_values) with [`multiple-value-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_multip.htm):

```
(multiple-value-bind (val pos) (parse-integer "12 3 6" :start 0 :junk-allowed t)
  (list val pos))
==> (12 2)
```

You can also [`setf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm) multiple [`values`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_values.htm):

```
(setf (values val pos) (parse-integer "12 3 6" :start 0 :junk-allowed t))
val ==> 12
pos ==> 2
```

See also [VALUES Forms as Places](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_abc.htm).

PS. In your particular case, you might just do

```
(read-from-string (concatenate 'string 
                               "("
                               "12 3 6"
                               ")"))
```

and get the list `(12 3 6)`.
This is not the most efficient way though (because it allocates unnecessary memory).

PPS See also:

1. [How to convert a string to list using clisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459501/850781)
2. [In lisp, how do I use the second value that the floor function returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6986880/850781)